Is the DAG produced by PC algorithm definitively causal?
We know that the structure of a Bayesian Network (BN), which is represented as a DAG, is not necessarily causal, while the structure of a Causal Bayesian Network (CBN) is. The question is, how do we obtain this DAG? Different methods applied to the same dataset can yield different DAGs—some causal, others not. The PC algorithm is one commonly used method. So, the question is straightforward: Is the DAG produced by the PC algorithm definitively causal?
Sorry it seems like such a stupid question, but I did think about it for a long time and couldn't come up with an answer.
